# DMN/FEEL (OMG) Implementation in Python

Tags: python

Is there any implementation of Friendly Enough Expression Language or any sub-parts of [Decision Modeling Notation](https://www.omg.org/spec/DMN/About-DMN/) (DMN) defined by Object Modeling Group (OMG)?

Comment: Are you looking for a ready-to-use software or for a library?

Comment: @Izzy I am looking for library, not for commercial SW.

Answer (score 2):

Yes - [pyDMNrules](https://pypi.org/project/pyDMNrules/) in an implementation of DMN in Python. It's available from PyPi.

You can install it with the command `pip install pyDMNrules`. This will also install pySFeel - a dependency and an implementation of S-FEEL (with a fair bit of FEEL thrown in for good measure - just no support for user defined functions).

Disclaimer: I am the author of pyDMNrules and pySFeel.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations SE Russell!  Can you add links to your answer?  Thanks!

Comment: ...about so. :-) Welcome on the SoftwareRecs SE!